# Create Report from 2 Datasets using Matrix with Report Builder SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I need help in building a report with Matrix using Report builder to produce the output below

[image]

I am using the following datasets

[image]

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious.. ar e you not able to join the data at the database level?

Comment: Union Join and groupby parent with an additional column did the trick. Thank you @Harry